# Global Naming CSS issue

Tags: css, reactjs

If I use the following approach in React:

```
import styles from './MyComponent.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={styles.foo}>Foo</div>
        <div className={styles.bar}>Bar</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is how to avoid this.For example, I have a div className = "first-div"
inside of this div i have a `<select> <input>` I will write CSS as

```
 .first-div> select, input{

...

}
```

If i have another div className = "second-div" and also `<select> <input>`
i will write CSS as

```
.second > select, input{

...

}
```

This input and select of both div's w will overwrite each other .. (global naming issue)
How to avoid this

Comment: I think there's only a global naming issue for your input tags.  When you do `.first-div > select, input`, you're applying the same style for `.first-div > select` and `input`.  Therefore, when you do `.second > select, input`, you're overriding `input` tag.  There shouldn't be any overriding for `.second > select` or `.first-div > select`.

Comment: By the way, if you have a select and input inside of first-div, you would use the following selector: `.first-div select, .first-div input`.